# Primefaces Sheet Can't Set Manual Entry For ColType Dropdown

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

`<pe:sheetcolumn headerText="smth" value="#{pojo.smth}" colWidth="200" colType="dropdown" selectItems="#{someBean.getMapItems('smth')}"/>` I want to set manual entry to dropdown column. But it doesnt let me do enter any manual value to this field. If i choose from dropdown it sets. But if i try to write something and trying to enter it doesnt let me to pass. If i remove `colType="dropdown"` i can add whatever i want.  I want to do same with colType="dropdown" as well.

I tried to add immediate = True or validate null to pe:sheetcolumn but it didnt work for me. How can i do that ?

My JSF VERSION : 2.2.1 PRİMEFACES AND PRIMEFACES EXTENSION VERSION : 6.2

Comment: You might want to use `colType="autocomplete"` instead, see [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/sheet.jsf#docuTabView:j_id_39)

Comment: @philipphutterer i tried that too. Its not let me set value

Comment: I add onvalidate to column add send postback true . It let me add now.